# Where is this Query Coming From?

Tags: sql-server-2017, query-store

I have enabled Query Store on SQL 2017, and I'm seeing at query that's occurring frequently doing a `SELECT *` on a specific table.

I would like to narrow down where this request is coming from and see if we can find a better way than doing the `SELECT *`.

I have a query id, of course, from Query Store. I've also recently asked my developers to include Application Name in their connection strings, which many have done.

Is there a way (perhaps using a DMV, for example) that I can find out the Application Name associated with this query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Query the query store DMVs for the query hash, then use that query hash in an Extended Events session to capture the pertinent details.

This should get you there:

```
SELECT qsq.query_hash
    , qsqt.query_sql_text
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
    INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
WHERE qsqt.query_sql_text LIKE '%some-pertinent-SQL%';
```

In the query above, I have `LIKE '%some-pertinent-SQL%'` - this limits the results of the query to match the target your looking for - you need to replace the `some-pertinent-SQL` with a unique piece of your target query.

Use the value from the `query_hash` column returned above in the Extended Events session definition:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [t] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name
    , sqlserver.client_hostname
    , sqlserver.nt_username
    , sqlserver.plan_handle
    , sqlserver.query_hash)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[query_hash]=(0x00000000))
    )
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (STARTUP_STATE=OFF);
GO
```

Replace the `0x00000000` with the actual query hash value.

Start the Extended Events session with:

```
ALTER EVENT SESSION [t] ON SERVER 
STATE = START;
```

Right-click the Extended Events session in Object Explorer to see details about the client hostname, username, etc., for queries as they happen.

[image]

To test this, I executed the following code on my SQL Server 2016 test instance:

```
CREATE DATABASE QueryStoreTest
ON PRIMARY 
(
      NAME = QueryStoreTest_primary
    , FILENAME = 'C:\temp\QueryStoreTest_primary.mdf'
    , SIZE = 100MB
    , FILEGROWTH = 100MB
    , MAXSIZE = 1000MB
)
LOG ON 
(
      NAME = QueryStoreTest_log
    , FILENAME = 'C:\temp\QueryStoreTest_log.ldf'
    , SIZE = 100MB
    , FILEGROWTH = 100MB
    , MAXSIZE = 1000MB
);
GO
ALTER DATABASE QueryStoreTest 
SET QUERY_STORE = ON;
```

Here, I'll create a couple of objects in the QueryStoreTest database, and a test query:

```
USE QueryStoreTest;
CREATE TABLE dbo.qst
(
    id int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.qst2
(
    id int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
);

SELECT *
/*  test query store query  */
FROM dbo.qst
    LEFT MERGE JOIN dbo.qst2 on qst.id = qst2.id;
```

Here, I'll get the query hash from the query store:

```
SELECT qsq.query_hash
    , qsqt.query_sql_text
FROM sys.query_store_query qsq
    INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt ON qsq.query_text_id = qsqt.query_text_id
WHERE qsqt.query_sql_text LIKE '%test query store query%';
```

Results:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║     query_hash     ║                     query_sql_text                     ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 0x3A0100223AD74766 ║ SELECT *  /*  test query store query  */  FROM dbo.qst ║
║                    ║  LEFT MERGE JOIN dbo.qst2 on qst.id = qst2.id          ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Now, I'll create the Extended Events Session:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [t] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed
(
    ACTION (
          sqlserver.client_app_name
        , sqlserver.client_hostname
        , sqlserver.nt_username
        , sqlserver.plan_handle
        , sqlserver.query_hash
    )
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[query_hash]=(0x3A0100223AD74766))
)
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

And start the session:

```
ALTER EVENT SESSION [t] ON SERVER 
STATE = START;
```

Now, if I run the test query and look at the live data from the session, I see:

[image]

Cleanup:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER EVENT SESSION [t] ON SERVER 
STATE = STOP;
GO
DROP EVENT SESSION [t] ON SERVER;
GO
ALTER DATABASE QueryStoreTest SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP DATABASE QueryStoreTest;
```